# Создать единичную матрицу. Ошибка TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, numpy, lambda

Мне необходимо создать единичную матрицу приблизительно следующим образом:

```
a = np.fromfunction(lambda x,y: int(x == y), (10,10))
```

Получаю ошибку:

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Хотя отдельно лямбда-функция работает:

[image: Отдельно функция работает]

Почему тогда возникает ошибка? И как это исправить?

Comment: Можете попробовать воспользоваться командой np.ones(число типа int ) для создания единичной матрицы .

Comment: вы хотите `np.eye(10)` или что-то другое?

Comment: @jfs Да, результат должен быть как у np.eye(10). Но дело в том, что если я напишу a = np.fromfunction(lambda x,y: x == y, (10,10)) - получу матрицу с True на главной диагонали. Пытаюсь перевести bool -> int в lambda и получаю ошибку. Хотя сама по себе lamda c int работает. Не могу понять, почему получаю ошибку

Comment: @НиколайЖурба и почему вы не хотите np.eye вызвать? (ошибка ясна и её можно исправить, но зачем исправлять если можно сразу правильную функцию вызвать)

Comment: @jfs Просто такое требование в лабораторной работе. Сделать одно и тоже разными методами

Comment: @НиколайЖурба: особые требования стоит прямо в вопросе указать, чтобы время не тратить на эти обмены. bool в int можно используя `.astype(int)` перевести для np массивов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x`, `y` у вас это не скаляры (такие как `1`,`0` как в примере в Питон REPL), а numpy массивы. Можно их напечатать:

```
def f(x, y):
    print(x)
    print(y)
    return x == y
```

Тогда:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.fromfunction(f, (3, 4))
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 2.  2.  2.  2.]]
[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
 [ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
 [ 0.  1.  2.  3.]]
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Видно, что `x`, `y` это массивы похожие на создаваемые [`numpy.meshgrid()` функцией](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html):

```
>>> y, x = np.meshgrid([0,1,2,3], [0,1,2])
>>> x
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2]])
>>> y
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

Если попробовать вызывать `int` на результате их сравнения, то возникнет ошибка:

```
>>> int(x == y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Чтобы в `int` превратить, [можно `.astype()` метод использовать](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html):

```
>>> (x == y).astype(int)
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Чтобы создать единичную матрицу, [можно `numpy.eye()` использовать](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html):

```
>>> np.eye(3, 4, dtype=int)
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот еще несколько способов создания единичной матрицы, не используя (`np.eye()` - метод предназначенный именно для этого).

Явное приведение типов:

```
N = 5

In [93]: np.fromfunction(lambda x,y: x==y, (N,N)).astype(np.int8)
Out[93]:
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=int8)
```

Неявное приведение типов (в результате умножения `np.bool` будет конвертирован в более "сильный" `np.int_` или `np.float_`, в зависимости от того на что умножить - на `1` или на `1.0`):

```
In [94]: np.fromfunction(lambda x,y: x==y, (N,N)) * 1
Out[94]:
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

In [105]: np.fromfunction(lambda x,y: x==y, (N,N)) * 1.0
Out[105]:
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Заполнение главной диагонали в нулевой матрице:

```
In [97]: a = np.zeros((N,N))

In [98]: a[np.diag_indices(N)] = 1

In [99]: a
Out[99]:
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```